# Nexus - find out against which artifacts and artifact was built

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management, nexus

For an artifact in Nexus, I want to find out the classpath, i.e. against which version of which artifact the artifact was built. Of course, parsing the pom gives some hints, but as we have parent POMs, dependency management etc., this is a difficult task.

I guess that Maven does not store this information in the jars or side artifacts automatically (at least I cannot find such a thing, a hint would be very welcome), but is there an easy way to adjust the build process so that Maven puts this information into the Nexus repository?

Comment: The [build-classpath](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) mojo of the dependency plugin seems helpful

Comment: You could also consult the maven dependency tree (if you need the information more structured than just in a list) `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 1):

Nexus doesn't provide such functionality. You can use the Maven dependency tree instead by invoking:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

If you use a CI (Continuous Integration) server (such as Hudson/Jenkins, Bamboo, TeamCity, etc), you can usually see which particular revisions of the snapshots were used for this build.

Comment: So if I want to see the concrete dependencies in Nexus, I should write the dependency tree to a file and add it the artifact?

Comment: Well, if you really must have it in a file -- I would assume -- "yes". Otherwise, you can always invoke the command locally and have a look at the tree.

Comment: If using `dependency:tree` use the correct [`scope`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#scope). Also not that there is currently a problem with it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3089

Comment: My actual aim is that I have programmatically accessible information in Nexus about the classpath/dependency-tree.

Comment: If you'd like an easily parsable flat list, then you might prefer using `mvn dependency:list`. Check here for more details: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html .